# Rails/delayed_job just... not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, delayed-job

I've spent about 3 hours trying to get a simple `delayed_job` to execute without success.  I have this extremely simple job:

```
class Foo
  def foo
    `echo foo >> /tmp/mrsmee`
  end
end
```

I'm enqueueing it in a Rails action like so:

```
Foo.new.delay.foo()
```

I'm running the job processor like so:

```
$ script/delayed_job run
```

I see a bunch of output logs like this,

```
2013-05-13T15:21:12-0700: [Worker(delayed_job host:asha.local pid:73263)] 1 jobs processed at 35.6405 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

and entries in the `delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs` like this,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51916452005056107900001a"), "priority" : 0, "attempts" : 0, "queue" : null, "handler" : "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/object:Foo {}\nmethod_name: :foo\nargs: []\n", "run_at" : ISODate("2013-05-13T22:08:18.560Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-05-13T22:08:18.560Z"), "created_at" : ISODate("2013-05-13T22:08:18.560Z") }
```

so clearly the jobs are being enqueued, processed, and dequeued.  Too bad the test output file, `/tmp/mrsmee`, never gets anything written to it.  I'm at a total loss.  Why isn't `delayed_job` actually running the delayed jobs, or at least telling me what's keeping it from doing so?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I had a similar problem with delayed job gem during several days. At the end I went with rufus-scheduler, don't know if your requirements allows that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit in late but:

The problem is not with DelayedJob but with you method. DelayedJob is executing Foo.new.foo.

If you try this:

```
class Foo
  def foo
    puts "hey!, the job is being executed!"
  end
end
```

and you see that string in the DelayedJob's output log, then delayedJob is working properly

Have you checked that rails (DelayedJob) has permissions to write in /tmp folder?

this code might help as well (test.txt is created and written in your app folder):

```
class Foo
  def foo
    `echo foo >> #{Rails.root.join "test.txt"}` #remember to delete test.txt!
  end
end
```

If this works, i.e. test.txt file is created and its content is foo, the problem should be something with permissions so `sudo script/delayed_job run` might help